# Accessing contents of a folder in iOS application bundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, bundle

I'm trying to access the contents of a specific folder in my Application Bundle to copy it somewhere else but whenever I go into a folder it seems to be giving me the contents of the entire bundle. Any idea how I can get the contents only in this folder?

**My Code**

```
-(void) moveAssets {

    NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSLog(@"%@", resourcePath);
    NSString *newPath = (@"%@/Test/",resourcePath);
    NSError * error;
    NSArray * directoryContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:newPath error:&error];

    for (NSString* currentString in directoryContents){
            NSLog(@"%@",currentString);
    }
}
```

**Logs**

Logs keep giving me all the files and not just the ones in the Test folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString *newPath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test"];
```

([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByAppendingPathComponent:)).